# If $m$ is an odd natural number, show that $m\mid 2^{\phi(m)}-1,$ where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> If $m$ is an odd natural number, show that $$m\mid 2^{\phi(m)}-1,$$ where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.
>
> ---

Can someone provide me some hints.

Comment: Euler and Fermat have something to say about it.

Comment: Do you not already know [Euler's generalization of Fermat's little Theoem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you want to prove is a straight consequence of Euler's totient theorem. On a  quick look at the theorem, you will find that:

> If $n$ and $a$ are coprime positive integers, then
>
> $${\displaystyle a^{\varphi (n)}\equiv 1{\pmod {n}}}$$

Since $m$ is odd (i.e. not divisible by $2$) and $2$ is prime, $m$ and $2$ are coprime, and hence you can apply Euler's totient theorem here, without any hesitation.